# How to combine SmoothScatter with the Pairs function in R

Tags: r

I have several predictors which I want to plot in a matrix by using `pairs()` in `R`.

To improve visibility I want to use transparent dots. Optimal is the `SmoothScatter` function. I have tried settings in rgb alpha too, although `SmoothScatter` gives the best results (in a 1 on 1 correlation instead of a matrix).

According to [this link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lumi/versions/2.24.0/topics/pairs-methods) `SmoothScatter` can be used in combination with `pairs()` too:

Although when I use :

```
pairs(mydataset, smoothScatter=TRUE)
```

I receive this error:

```
In plot.window(...) : "smoothScatter" is not a graphical parameter
```

Is there a method to use `smoothScatter` in the `pairs()` function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the plotting function to `pairs()` through the `panel` argument

```
pairs(mydataset, panel=function(x,y){smoothScatter(x,y,add=T)})
```